# TYPO3 6.2x extBase RTE parse

Tags: fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, rte

I want to parse RTE content in TYPO3 6.2.9 extBase. I have tried:

```
$cObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$parseContent= $cObj->parseFunc($content, array(), '< lib.parseFunc_RTE');

$parseContent=\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Plugin\AbstractPlugin::pi_RTEcssText($content);

$cObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer');
parseContent= $cObj->parseFunc($content, array(), '< lib.parseFunc_RTE' );
```

[screenshot of the resulting html](http://screencast.com/t/wd2dNMUEfD)

How can I parse RTE content?

Comment: more details! where do you want to parse it ? within contorller, view? what exactly T3 are you using, you tagged with 6.2 but trying depraciated `tslib_cObj`... we can't guess

Comment: I have extend seminar ext. Some where I need to more functionality, so I made extBase extension named seminarsystem. here I need to resend email and template must be from seminar ext. so I need to parse RTE data in controller.

Comment: sligthly improved code formatting: an empty line is sufficient to express the three tries, put the link in a more meaningful text

Comment: I got solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267124/php-script-is-parsing-content-from-rte-tt-news-but-internal-links-are-not-appe

$parseObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('t3lib_parsehtml_proc'); 
$txt = $parseObj->TS_links_rte($bodytext);
$seminarDescription = $parseObj->TS_transform_rte($txt);

It's work for me!

Comment: You should use a fluid template as your email template, you don't have to parse RTE content then.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Cobj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$htmloutput= $Cobj->parseFunc($myquerywithcontentvariable , array(), '< lib.parseFunc_RTE');
```

And of course Also use defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css] in your TCA file

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function for the same

```
private function formatHtml($value) {
        $contentObject = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class);
        $content = $contentObject->parseFunc($value, array(), '< lib.parseFunc_RTE');
        return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alongwith RTE option  **enableRichText="1"**   please append this option as well  **defaultExtras="richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css]"**

This might help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$parseProcObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class);
$parseProcObj->parseFunc($value, array(), '< lib.parseFunc_RTE')
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).